# Find the value of $\int_{1}^{100} \frac{ [x] }{x} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I've been asked to evaluvate
$$\int_{1}^{100} \frac{ [x] }{x} dx$$
where $[x]$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)

This is what I tried to do

$$ \int_{1}^{100} \frac{ [x] }{x} dx =  \int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{x}dx+2\int_2^3 \frac{1}{x}dx + \int_{3}^{4} \frac{ 3 }{x}dx+.....$$

which comes out to
$$\ln(2)-\ln(1)+2\ln(3)-2\ln(2)+3\ln(4)-3\ln(3) \dots =5\ln(2)-\ln(3)  $$ and so on.

However, this doesn't yield any recognizable pattern.

What other methods will be suitable here?

Comment: $$\ln(2)-\ln(1)+2\ln(3)-2\ln(2) + ... + 99\ln(100)-99\ln(99) =\ln\left(\dfrac{100^{99}}{99!}\right) $$

Comment: Can be also written as $\ln\frac{100^{100}}{100!}$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, thanks, but how do I actually compute the sum manually

Comment: Well, this sum rearranges as $$99\ln(100)-\ln(1)-\ln(2)-\ln(3)-...-\ln(99)$$

Comment: and then using the property $a(lnb) = lnb^a$ and $lna-lnb = ln\frac{a}{b}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}\int_1^{100} \frac{[x]}{x} d x 
& =\sum_{k=1}^{99} \int_k^{k+1} \frac{[x]}{x} d x \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^{99} \int_k^{k+1} \frac{k}{x} d x \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^{99} k[\ln x]_k^{k+1} \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^{99}(k \ln (k+1)-k \ln k) \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^{99} k \ln (k+1)-\sum_{k=1}^{99} k \ln k \\
& =\sum_{k=2}^{100}(k-1) \ln k-\sum_{k=2}^{99} k \ln k \\
& =\sum_{k=2}^{100} k \ln k-\sum_{k=2}^{99} k \ln k-\sum_{k=2}^{100} \ln k \\
& =100 \ln 100-\ln (100!) \\
OR &=\ln \left(\frac{100^{100}}{100 !}\right) \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Note that it's numerically much better to keep the big numbers outside the logarithm to avoid the need for computing big numbers such as $100^{100}$ and $100!$.